# After Upgrading Robot Framework to 3.1.1 the variable concatenation does not work

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

After recently upgrading my robot framework version from 3.0 to 3.1.1 my variable which I used to concatenate directly like 
`Element Should Be Visible    ${el}[contains(@class,'icon-expanded')]` does no work any longer.
I have found a workaround which needs me to explicitly concatenate the varible instead of using it directly like specified above

```
${el1} =   Catenate    SEPARATOR=    ${el}   [contains(@class,'icon-expanded')]
Element Should Be Visible    ${el1}
```

I can not see anything in the release notes which says this no longer is working. Is there any other way rather than using explicit concatenation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a regression in robot framework 3.1, not 3.1.1. The release notes that describes this regression is under the heading [Square brackets after variable like ${var}[xxx] is considered item access](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#square-brackets-after-variable-like-var-xxx-is-considered-item-access)

> Syntax like ${var}[xxx] is now considered variable item access (#2601), not variable ${var} followed by a literal string [xxx]. If the latter is desired, escaping like ${var}[xxx] is needed.

Basically, anything in square brackets immediately following a variable are treated as an index into the variable.

You can work around this by escaping the bracket:

```
Element Should Be Visible    ${el}\[contains(@class,'icon-expanded')]
```

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks a lot. I missed that release comment.